# Installing flask mysqldb

Tags: python, flask-mysql

When i run pip install flask-mysql db is get this error:

> _mysql.c(29) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory.

Comment: Have you installed the msql-dev package?

Answer (score 1):

Download you version from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python .
Then just run "pip install mysqlclient-1.3.12-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl"

Answer (score 0):

After spending a half day to search for a solution. I closed the VSCode. Started Anaconda terminal. Change directory an active environtment

```
(myflaskappevn):
```

In my case:

```
(myflaskappevn) D:\myflaskapp>Code .
```

When VSCode open, from terminal:

```
pip install flask_mysqldb
```

It worked.
So I installed the following

```
pip install flask_mysqldb
pip install flask_mysql db
```

Worked fine as well but it is not needed.

```
pip install Flask_WTF
pip install passlib
pip install mysql-connector-python
pip install mysql-connector
```

I hope that would help someone out there.